# Recommended approach to load data to a Pandas DataFrame with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

Say I have a table in a SQL database. To retrieve data from this table with SQLAlchemy (no ORM for now) I can use either of these two options:

```py
from sqlalchemy import text
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
import pandas as pd


query = "SELECT * FROM employees"

# Option 1
with SessionLocal() as session:
    df = pd.read_sql_query(text(query), session.connection())
    print(df.head())

# Option 2
with SessionLocal() as session:
    df = pd.DataFrame(session.execute(text(query)))
    print(df.tail())
```

What are the advantages and differences of using each, if any?

Comment: `pd.read_sql_query` (Option 1) will do the same `session.connection.execute(text(query))`, but wading through additional abstractions, wrappers and checks